# Magento 2: How to use Multi Language in XML File

Tags: magento2, xml, custom, language

As in **phtml** file we use

```
<?php echo __('Title'); ?>
```

to Support Multi Language.

How to use same in XML File for Title

**app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\mymodule_index_index.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: First you check your xml file name @AnkitShah, like this app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\mymodule_index_index.xml

Comment: @PayalPatel What's wrong?

Comment: Your xml file name here `app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\mymodule_inde_index.xml` @AnkitShah

Comment: Aahh. It's Type Mistake. Will update in question. Wait a min. Done

Comment: Okk. Fine @AnkitShah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```